# Why was I suspended for this review?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I noticed that I have been suspended for a few hours, but I don't understand why.

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17178936 wasn't helpful; please review the history of the post and consider how choosing a different action could've helped achieve that outcome more quickly.

I voted to delete, as did the other 2 reviewers. The answer under review didn't seem to answer the question, and there are multiple errors with spelling and punctuation.

I'm not sure what would be the appropriate action. Should I correct the spelling mistakes?

I'm not aware of any other recent incorrect reviews that I might have done or audits I have failed. It seems strange that this review alone would lead to a suspension. I'm not sure what I should learn from this. How can I improve to avoid future review suspensions?

Comment: So what is the definition of "very low quality"? Surely readability has some relevance? I'm not claiming that spelling mistakes should be reason enough to delete an answer.

Comment: VLQ is hard. A decent guideline is "if this is a good-faith attempt, keep it around". There's a healthy amount of debate over the purpose of the VLQ flag (and whether it should even exist)

Comment: In this case my main consideration was that it looked to me like something that should be comment instead of an answer. But I could be wrong about that.

Comment: It ultimately says "you can't do that, for these reasons" - which is an (attempt to) answer, even if not an encouraging one.

Comment: Thanks for translating it for me. That seems like a plausible interpretation of the answer.

Comment: All this discussion, yet *no one* has edited that answer yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a manual review suspension, from me. Stijn's answer is correct; see [Shog's mSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [my LQP-specific post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664) for guidance.

Some folks are being overzealous with the recommend-delete button. When I see it happen, I try to get their attention in some way - sometimes a comment when it's convenient, sometimes a one-day review ban. I don't want to come down hard on folks that are trying to help, but doing it in the wrong way - those are the folks we want to keep around.

The message isn't great. I'm going to try to customize that to something more descriptive - but in this case, it's obviously worked to draw your attention. Thanks for being willing to learn!

Comment: That seems reasonable. And it would be helpful to receive some kind of specific notification about why a review was incorrect. Especially when all the reviewers voted to delete.

Comment: It would. I'll try to customize that message in the future. This is a hard case to self-diagnose because I dismissed the flag (thus invalidating the review task) and you have no visibility into that process - you just see a unanimous review that ended mysteriously. Definitely room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it answers the question. Question asks how to do X, answer advises against doing X, because of reasons. So it shouldn't have been deleted.

Spelling errors should be fixed through editing, they are not at all a reason to delete a post, unless the content is absolute gibberish.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I have to admit that I had problems understanding the content of the answer because of the spelling and grammar. So I guess if I can't make out the meaning of an answer, I should click "Skip" and let others figure it out?

Comment: @HåkenLid It doesn't have to be correct, it just has to look like an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Correct, @HåkenLid - there's a line between "I can't understand this (skip)" and "no one could ever understand this because it's gibberish (delete)". In general, though, if you believe it's a good-faith attempt to answer you shouldn't try to delete it.

Comment: @HåkenLid yep, if you do not fully understand what's in the post you need to validate, then you should click on skip. You cannot make an informed decision without understanding the post first.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that if something was completely incomprehensible to everyone because of spelling errors, nobody should vote to delete or be able to correct it?